# How to match a string with an optional "/" at the end?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match a URL such as;

http://www.testing.com/documents/dashboard

What I want is to match "/documents/dashboard" or "/documents/dashboard/". How can be this done?

```
preg_match('/^\/documents\/dashboard[\/|]$/i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

This doesn't work? What should I enter after pipe (|) character in [] block to cover "nothing" as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url+regex

Comment: Sorry I was too hasty with the close option, disregard that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[\/|]$` is wrong, because `[]` creates a character class. So what you are matching there is `/` or `|` followed by end of string. To do what you were thinking of:

```
preg_match('~^/documents/dashboard(/|$)$~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Although I think it's easier to use:

```
preg_match('~^/documents/dashboard/?$~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

`/?` means match the `/` character 1 or 0 times.

Tip: If you use a delimiter other than `/`, you won't have to escape forward slashes in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/^\/documents\/dashboard\/?$/i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

People often use it at the end of their regex, but it can in fact be used anywhere. Although in your case it's just simpler to use the `?` quantifier.

Or, if you absolutely want to use `$`, the following would work too:

```
/^\/documents\/dashboard(\/|$)$/i
```

Comment: Oh, yeah. Better use `(\/|$)$`. But in that case using `?` is simpler.

Comment: No it isn't, if you remove it `/documents/dashboard/blabla` would match too.

Comment: I tried \/|$ but it didn't work. However ? works great. Thanks!